Finite difference of a product of functions
If I have the following equation:
$\large \frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial  (x f(x,t) g(x,t)) }{\partial x}$
and I want to solve it numerically using a finite difference method (FDM), is it more accurate to apply the partial derivative to the product of functions on the RHS and then apply the FDM to each of the resulting derivative terms in the result i.e. fg + xgdf/dx +xfdg/dx ? or is it more accurate to let some variable say A =xf(x,t)*(g(x,t) in which case the equation can be written as
$\large \frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial A(x,t)}{\partial x}$
and then apply the FDM to the RHS in which case it could be written as for example A[i,j+1] = A[i,j] + (A[i+1,j] - A[i-1,j])/2dx for a centered difference? And is there a way to mathematically prove one is more accurate than the other perhaps via a Taylor series approximation?
Any help is greatly appreciated.
